# Return a string as private inherited class in c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a class which privately inherits `std::string`. I want to have a member function which returns the `string` that is the base class. How do I do it?

```
class NewClass() : private std::string
{
    ...
public:
    std::string GetString() const;
    ...
};

std::string NewClass::GetString() const
{
  ???
}
```

Comment: If you want to be able to return a `string` anyway, why not just inherit `public`ly so that you don't need this function at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off keeping a `std::string` as a private member of `NewClass`. So you would declare it as :

```
class NewClass
{
private:
     std::string str;
...
public:
    std::string GetString() const;
};
...
std::string NewClass::GetString() const
{
    return str;
}
```

However if you really need to inherit from `std::string` you could do

```
std::string NewClass::GetString() const
{
    return *this;
};
```

but be warned that this will cut out any parts of your derived class. It would be better to do something like this:

```
const std::string& NewClass::GetString() const
{
    return *this;
};
```

which will return a reference to the std::string `NewClass` has inherited from.

Comment: Thanks! I know containment may be better but I just happen to have this question.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#include <string>

class NewClass
    : private std::string
{
public:
    const std::string& GetString() const{
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    NewClass c;
    const std::string& the_string = c.GetString();
    return 0;
}
```

[Live working example](http://ideone.com/7c9Rkp)

Comment: Thanks! Two answers here are basically same.